# how to plot data upside down

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting two sets of data (*dataA*, *dataB*). Each of the dataset is 431(x axis) x 64 (y axis). When I plot them, the data are plotted on the x axis from bottom to top (i.e., at the bottom A, B, C, D, etc.). Instead, I would like to plot them from top to bottom (i.e., at the top A, B, C, D, etc.).

Also, I am not sure how to plot vertical lines every 10 points, and not every point.

I am using this code:

```
 %Plot
 figure;
 gray = [0.8 0.8 0.8];
 patch([1 431 431 1],[1 1 23 23],gray) % Add a patch
 patch([1 431 431 1],[42 42 64 64],gray) % Add a patch

 hold on

 pcolor(dataA)
 colormap(jet);

 hold on

 pcolor(dataB)
 colormap(jet);

 hold on

 LineFormatVert.LineWidth = 5;
 MarkerFormat.MarkerSize = 12;
 MarkerFormat.Marker = '*';

 xt={'1'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '6' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  '14'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '19'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '24'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '29'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '34'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '39'    ''  ''  ''  ''  '44'};

 yt = {'','','A','','','','','','B','','','','','','C','','','','D','','','E','','','F','','','','','','','G','','','','','','H','','I','','','','L','','','','','','M','','','','','','N','','','','O','','','P',''};
 grid on
 set(gca,'layer','top') %to have grid on top of the patch

 set(gcf,'color','white') %white background outside the figure
 set(gca,'yticklabel', yt);
 set(gca, 'ytick',1:64);
 set(gca, 'xticklabel',xt);

 set(gca, 'xtick',1:10:431);
 title('Title - Data A and Data B');
 xlabel('X Label');
 ylabel('Y Label');
 set(gca, 'FontSize', 20, 'fontweight','bold')
```

Comment: `set(gca,'ydir','reverse')` ?

Comment: You had just deleted a question about grid lines that I was about to answer. Did you figure it out for yourself? If not, you just needed to turn off the edge color for the `pcolor` plot.

Comment: @gnovice, yes I figured it out, thanks anyway. I used: `B = pcolor(dataB);
set(B,'edgecolor','none');`